# TFS 2015 upgrade issue when forcing language

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, upgrade, tfs-2015

I started a project using TFS 2013. Once TFS 2015 came out I forced to update from 2013 changing the installation language from Spanish to English.

Now, when I try to upgrade to TFS 2015 Update 1, I can't upgrade because of the following error:

[image]

I've followed these steps to try to fix the issue:

- I've installed English language pack on Windows (it's a Windows Server 2012 R2).
- I've enabled English as display language on Windows too.
- I've changed the locale to English on regional settings.

Now I'm not sure what I should do next. Is there any way to force the whole upgrade? I'm absolutely stuck with this because until I can upgrade this TFS installation, I won't be able to access the web portal, use GIT...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was easy. Reading the whole message carefully I realized that the SQL Server installation itself wasn't the English version. Once I've re-installed SQL Server in English the issue was solved.